# NSImage w/ BitmapImageRep -> CIImage to invert color -> NSImage w/ BitmapImageRep, colorspace issues

Tags: cocoa, core-image, nsimage, color-space, ciimage

So I have an `NSImage *startingImage`
It is represented by an `NSBitmapImageRep` with a gray colorspace

I need to invert the colors on it, so I convert it to a `CIImage`

```
  CIImage *startingCIImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:(NSBitmapImageRep*)[startingImage representations][0]];
  CIFilter *invertColorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"CIColorInvert")];
  [invertColorFilter setValue:startingCIImage forKey:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"inputImage")];
  CIImage *outputImage = [invertColorFilter valueForKey:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"outputImage")];
```

If I view the `outputImage` at this point, it is exactly what I expect, the same image except with inverted colors.

I then convert it back into an `NSImage` like so:

```
   NSBitmapImageRep *finalImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:outputImage];
   NSImage *finalImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[finalImageRep size]];
   [finalImage finalImageRep];
```

Here's my issue...  My original `NSImage` has a Gray colorspace, and 8 bits per pixel.

```
<NSImage 0x610000071440 Size={500, 440} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6100002a1800 Size={500, 440} ColorSpace=Device Gray colorspace BPS=8 BPP=8 Pixels=500x440 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=0
CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x6100001ab0c0>" )>
```

However, after I convert everything, and log out the image, this is what I have

```
<NSImage 0x61800127e540 Size={500, 440} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6080000b8cc0 Size={500, 440} ColorSpace=ASUS PB278 colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=500x440 Alpha=YES Planar=NO
Format=0 CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x6180001a3f00>" )>
```

And as you may know, `NSBitmapImageRep` is meant to be immutable, and when I  try `setColorSpaceName` or `setAlpha`, the image ends up just being a black box.

Is there something I'm missing so that I can convert my `NSImage` into a `CIImage`, invert the black and white, then convert back into an `NSImage`?

Comment: `NSBitmapImageRep`'s `initWithCIImage` renders the image using the current graphics context.

Comment: The CGContextRef? I can only set the color space of the fill or stroke, and when I try setting it nothing changes on the NSImage

Comment: I'm not an images expert. I suggest you read the documentation of `initWithCIImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could replace the color space at the end:

```
NSBitmapImageRep* fixedRep = [finalImageRep bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace: [startingImageRep colorSpace]
    renderingIntent: NSColorRenderingIntentDefault];
```